# accessing a value in a sub array

Tags: php, arrays

i am new to php and a bit confused about accessing a value in an array.

the array is below. the issue for me is that i want to access a value in the array.

for example, i want to access the £80.00 figure below

i.e the £80.00 figure is contained in a **subarray** that holds a value=key of **amountString**

```
Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => amountString
            [1] => £80.00
        )

   [13] => Array
    (
        [0] => name
        [1] => testname
    )

}
```

thank you

UPDATE

this is how i generated this array. i got it from a http object
i.e:

```
POST /fail?installation=XXXXXX&msgType=authResult HTTP/1.0
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
 Host: 
 Content-Length: 973
 User-Agent: WJHRO/1.0 ( HTTP Request Object)

 region=new+format+region&authAmountString=%26%23163%3B10.00&_SP.charEnc=UTF8&desc=&tel=&address1=new+format+address1)
```

i then did the following to get the array:

```
$data = explode('&', $post);


            foreach($data as &$entry) {
                 $entry = explode('=', $entry);
                 $entry[1] = urldecode($entry[1]);
            }
            unset($entry);
```

Comment: Access it by `Array[12][1]`

Comment: You have printed it in an easy to read way. Let's say the outer ("first") array has the variable name $data, then it's just to read your way into the data you want. $data[12][1]

Comment: the problem is that the number are likely to change each time. is there any other way to read the values without using the numbers

Comment: How are these arrays being generated? Are you able to output associative arrays? `$array['client']['amount'] = '80.00';`? Something like that?

Comment: hi Rasclatt. i have added more code to show how the array was formatted. i hope it helps

Comment: Instead of doing the splitting and decoding yourself, you could simply use `parse_str($post, $data);`.

Answer (score 0):

i went about it the wrong way.

a simple solution is to use the [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function and then simply access the variables directly.

eg:

```
  $contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
  parse_str($contents,$postArray);
```